# Kernel of orthogonal projection on an eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection, projection-matrices

let $Q$ be a $d\times d $-matrix  and $P:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be the orthogonal projection on the eigenspace $E_0 $ of $Q$. Why is the kernel of the projection the sum of the other eigenspaces of $Q$? 
Is it right at all?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not right. Suppose that $d=2$, and that $Q=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Then $E_0=\langle(1,0)\rangle$ and the kernel of the orthogonal projection on that space is $\langle(0,1)\rangle$. However, the direct sum of the other eigenspaces is $\langle(1,1)\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then i missed an argument in the article that i study. Perhaps more assumptions on Q.

Comment: @Thomas_R If $Q$ is a symmetric (or normal) matrix, it works.